# how to filter data on different sheets based on clicks on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How to filter data on different worksheets based on clicks in Tableau. For example:

**Sheet 1** - The partition looks like this:

```
+------+-------+-----+
| Name | Month | ... |
+------+-------+-----+
| A    | Jan   | ... |
| B    | Jan   | ... |
| C    | Feb   | ... |
| D    | Mar   | ... |
| ...  | ...   | ... |
+------+-------+-----+
```

**Sheet 2** - The partition includes Month.

When I click on Jan on Sheet 1, can Tableau filter Jan on Sheet 2?

I tried including an URL and making the filter universal to all sheets but filter doesn't work "on click" does it?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording. Is a "sheet" a Tableau worksheet? Is the data in each worksheet coming from the same datasource? Are you saying that your first Tableau worksheet includes the fields `Name` and `Month`, and your second Tableau worksheet includes the field `Month`, and that you'd like to be able to click on the viz in Sheet 1 to filter Sheet 2?

Comment: HI,
Everything that you have assumed is correct.
There are 2 worksheets, The first sheet includes fields Name and Month
And yes I want to click on Jan on Sheet 1 to filter data(Jan) on sheet 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Filter actions are an essential and fundamental tool in Tableau, and you're going to want to master them fast, so I'd recommend hitting up [this help page](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#qs_actions_filter.html) for a good overview of how they work.

Go to **Actions…** (if you're on a dashboard, you can access this menu from **Dashboard**, or access the same menu from **Worksheet** if you're working from a worksheet). Select **Add Action >** and choose **Filter**. Your source sheet (the sheet that will control the filter) will be Sheet 1. Your target sheet (the sheet that will be filtered) will be Sheet 2. Hit **Select** under **Run action on:**.

At the bottom of the menu, under **Target Filters**, choose **Selected Fields**. This will allow you to filter only the specific fields you define in this menu. Hit **Add Filter...** and choose `Month` for the source and the target. You've now created a filter from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 that will only filter based on `Month`.

It's possible that you don't need to be that specific and can actually filter all fields. There's a quick way to do that if the sheets are in a dashboard. Click the dropdown menu at the top right of Sheet 1 in the dashboard and select **Use as Filter**. This will automagically create a filter using all fields from that sheet to all other sheets on the dashboard. If you need to tweak it, you can go to that same **Actions...** menu we just discussed, select the filter from the list, and change any of the things we discussed above from there.

Comment: That help page link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

A filter can be used across multiple worksheets. On the filter triangle, select "Apply to worksheets" --> "Selected Worksheet". By default it will show only the worksheets in the current dashboard. At the bottom, check box show all worksheets. You can then select any sheet you want to apply the filter to.