# Tableau how to carry filter from Sheet1 to Sheet2, then to Sheet3?

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

In Tableau I have two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2, among others in a dashboard. The first sheet, Sheet1 contains Field1 and Field2.  If I click anywhere on Sheet1, then it will filter Sheet2 on both Field1 and Field2.  Sheet2 has a Field3.  If I click on Sheet2 then a filter action takes me to another dashboard which it filters on Field3.

Currently the filter action from Sheet1 to Sheet2 works and the filter action from Sheet2 to the other dashboard also works.  My problem arises when I use them together.  If I click on Sheet1 to filter Sheet2 (by Field1 and Field2), then click on Sheet2 then it filters the other dashboard on only Field3.  How could I make it so that when I do this, it will filter the other dashboard on Field1, Field2, and Field3.  In other words, how can I carry through the filter from Sheet1 to Sheet2 and then to the other dashboard?

Here is a screenshot of its current behavior.  Obviously, data has been redacted.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722458/how-to-filter-data-on-different-sheets-based-on-clicks-on-tableau

Comment: Aron: No, it isn't.  I'm already using filter actions which is how I'm filtering `Sheet2` by clicking on `Sheet1` and filtering the other dashboard by clicking on `Sheet2`.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I think you can do that in the actions window - open your dashboard and go to Dashboard > Actions and press Add Action. On this screen, you can select the "Target Sheets" - you can select a sheet that is using the same data source* even if the sheet isn't on the 'starting' dashboard. At the bottom of this pane, you can select which fields to apply the filter to - "all fields" may work, or you may have to specify the fields* In version 10, you can do cross-datasource filtering, but that's a separate discussion. Can you try that and see if it works?

Comment: update -- you can actually build this filter at the sheet level, so you can create an action that 'starts' at sheet 2 (instead of the dashboard) with a target of sheet 3, but you can only access the "actions" window from within a dashboard, which is kind of weird. hope that makes sense

Comment: Aron:  I created another filter action to separately filter the Sheet3.  So now, one action causes Sheet2 to be filtered and another causes Sheet3 to be filtered, after clicking on Sheet1.  The issue now is that if I click on Sheet1, then it automatically jumps over to Sheet3 instead of just filtering it in the background in case I happen to click on sheet2.